# Playing all files in a folder in VLC?

Tags: windows, windows-10, vlc-media-player, playlists

I want to watch all files in a folder with multiple mp4s using VLC Media Player.  When I right-click on a folder there are two options:

`play with vlc media player`

`add to VLC media player's Playlist`

What is the difference between these two options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my Windows 7 the associated commands (in the rigistry) are:

*play...*

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" --started-from-file --no-playlist-enqueue "%1"
```

*add to...*

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" --started-from-file --playlist-enqueue "%1"
```

I find [VideoLAN's Wiki](https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help) to be rather enigmatic when it comes to the difference between the two:

> --playlist-enqueue, --no-playlist-enqueue
>   Enqueue items to playlist when in one instance mode (default disabled)
>   When using the one instance only option, enqueue items to playlist and keep playing current item. (default disabled)

My VLC adds media to its playlist either way. The difference is *play* plays the first of newly added media at once, while *add* doesn't interfere with current playback (or idle state). This is by observation only. I'm not smart enough to conclude this behavior from the documentation cited.